# What is the highest score recorded for a single play in Words with Friends

Tags: words-with-friends

You can only play 7 tiles in one turn in Words with Friends, so that makes a maximum of eight words you can make at once. By maximizing use of the bonus squares (Triple Word Score etc.) you can get some very high scores.

What is the highest score anyone has achieved in a single turn in Words with Friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to recordsetter.com the current record for a single word turn is [1674 points](https://recordsetter.com/world-record/highest-point-value-give-for-single-word-game-words-with-friends/15990) with the word *"oxyphenbutazone"*.

This word has been used for various other records such as [1670](https://recordsetter.com/world-record/highest-point-value-give-for-single-word-game-words-with-friends/5303), [1672](https://recordsetter.com/world-record/highest-point-value-give-for-single-word-game-words-with-friends/6623) and [1673](https://recordsetter.com/world-record/highest-point-value-give-for-single-word-game-words-with-friends/15967) points.

It's worth mentioning that most of these records have been set by setting up the game in a way that optimized for this specific play.